# Sqoop Import from Mysql to Hadoop hdfs Using Java

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to load into HDFS from Mysql Using Java. My Hadoop Version 2.7.2 and Sqoop 1.4.6. I am getting the following exception

> ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException
>   as:xxxx cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC
>   version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4 16/11/16 17:40:57
>   ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job:
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot
>   communicate with client version 4

Here is the code

```
public void importData() {
    SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions();
    options.setConnectString("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Sample");
    options.setUsername("UserName");
    options.setPassword("Password");
    options.setNumMappers(1);
    options.setSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE $CONDITIONS       limit 10");
   options.setHadoopMapRedHome(HADOOP_HOME);
   options.setTargetDir(WAREHOUSE_DIR);
   int ret = new ImportTool().run(options);
}
```

I have added the following dependencies

```
apache-logging-log4j.jar
commons.io_2.0.1.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.7.jar
commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
sqoop-1.4.6.jar
```

Help me to sort this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Hadoop Version 2.7.2.

but in dependency it has hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar which is for hadoop 1.x

replace `hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar` with hadoop-common.jar -> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.2

hope this helps

Comment: I removed the hadoop core jar and added hadoop-common.jar 2.7.2 it asked for other few dependencies i added that now getting the following exception Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName.

Comment: what is the necessity of doing this way when sqoop provides alternate ways to export tables to hdfs. one such way is writing the data to a file using sql and then copying the file to hdfs.Field delimiter and line delimiter can also be specified. Example <select * from categories into outfile '/home/table_name.csv' fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';>